# Open USB Relay - Android

Tags: android, linux, bash

I have KMtronics USB relay which I want to control with my Android device. Is it possible to run the following Linux command:

```
#!/bin/sh
# sends on signal to the USB relay
echo -e '\xff\x01\x01' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I tried to execute same command with some Shell Executor apps but always either getting `Permission Denied` or `Unable to create file/folder`. Even I tried to run it on Rooted device too.

Comment: Run the script with `sudo` permissions.

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*` say? Do you have all needed permissions?

Comment: /dev/ttyUSB*:No such file or directory :(

Comment: It seems like your USB port does not support host mode. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html and take a look at the output of dmesg.

Comment: Example of HID USB Relays in Android : https://github.com/gigacycle/AndroidHidUsbRelayControl

Answer (score 0):

Permission problem could be solved like this:

```
echo -e '\xff\x01\x01' | sudo dd of=/dev/ttyUSB0
```